# Setup filename convention? setup.exe vs install.exe vs others

Tags: installation, naming-conventions, windows-installer

I'm going to build an installer to deploy my application which is a Windows executable file(not a MSI file). I'm using NSIS. This application targets French people and "install" word is close to "installation" in French.

Is there a filename convention? What is the best choice for you?

It seems that "setup.exe" is the most popular name compare to "install.exe"

What do you think?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setup.exe` is definitely the most popular convention in the Windows world. I'd say go with that.

Comment: Yes. In addition, my hypothesis is that install.exe was slightly more popular in the past.

Comment: But then, if you download multiple installers for multiple apps, you won't be able to differentiate them.

Comment: @gonadarian that convention is definitely for when you have an installation medium or ZIP file and needed to locate the correct executable in it. Now, eight years later, when most software is distributed via downloads, it's more common to name the package after the program, yeah.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes setup.exe is used for install, repair and remove application. I think there is no good answer for this question. I prefer such names as `application_installer` or `application_setup`. Even in one organization there is `Firefox Setup 3.5.6.exe` and `sunbird-0.3.pl.win32.installer.exe`.

Comment: I didn't think about that but you're right, application name with version number should be good choice. 
eg "myapplication_101.exe" (with underscore between I dont like spaces into filename!)

Comment: `Firefox Setup 114.0.1.exe` is still used. Electron also defaults to `[Product Name] Setup [version].exe`. Microsoft Edge is `MicrosoftEdgeSetup.exe` (which is a wrapper onto the actual file download).

Answer (score 0):

I'd never really thought about it... but having done just that - setup is really the wrong word and install is, I suppose, the correct term.

You're installing the software, so I would go with install... setup implies it has already been installed (unless your changing settings during the install) - either way you are still installing something.

Comment: Except many installers detect whether you already have the stuff installs and does an upgrade, or allow you to uninstall, or remove/add parts of the thing. i.e. it's setup